# add limit for list in for loop django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates

I want to print only 10 elements from list in Django template

here is my code

```
<ul>
    <h3>Positive Tweets :</h3>
    {% for tweet in positiveTweet %}
      <li>{{ tweet.0 }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How can I print first 10 elements if positiveTweet list having length of 100 something.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `slice` to make this:

```
<ul>
    <h3>Positive Tweets :</h3>
    {% for tweet in positiveTweet|slice:":10" %}
      <li>{{ tweet.0 }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

See the [Django Slice Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice).

Comment: in box? what means "in box" ?

Answer (score 4):

The Django way is to construct a Paginator over the result set in the view, then look at properties of the Page in your template, see [the Django pagination documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/) for full details.

For instance if my News objects are available like this:

```
def index(request):
    news = News.objects.filter(published=True).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags')
    paginator = Paginator(news, 10)
    page_obj = paginator.page(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    return render(request, 'front.html', {'news': page_obj})
```

In the template, you are given a Page object, which will hold 10 items at a time and have several useful properties you can wire into a UI pager. For instance the [bootstrap pager  is wired](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination) a bit like this:

```
{% for post in news %}
  <h3>{{ post.headline }}</h3>
  {{ post.body }}
{% endfor %}

<nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if news.has_previous %}
    <li>
      <a href="?page={{news.previous_page_number}}" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for p in news.paginator.page_range %}
    <li class="{% if news.number == p %}active{% endif %}"><a href="?page={{p}}">{{p}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if news.has_next %}
    <li>
      <a href="?page={{news.next_page_number}}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check for the loop counter like this:

```
          {% for tweet in positiveTweet %}

               {% if forloop.counter < 11 %}

                <!-- Do your something here -->

               {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -3):

Likewise, a loop that stops processing after the 10th iteration:

```
{% for user in users %}
{%- if loop.index >= 10 %}{% break %}{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

loop.index starts with 1, and loop.index0 starts with 0.

Visit the below link for details: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for-loop